# Insert Table Rows After an Existing Row

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have an MVC app and one of the pages calls a controller method via ajax that then returns a partial view which has a large number of table rows.  Note that a full table isn't returned but just the table rows.

I need to add those table rows at a specific position in the table.  I have a reference to the table that the rows need to be added after (or before really as the referenced row will be removed after the new rows are added).  Using jQuery this would be ridiculously simple:

```
$(newRows).insertAfter(tr);
tr.remove();
```

The problem is that the newRows html could be very very large and I have found inserting them via jQuery can take quite some time.  Inserting the rows without jQuery, just through pure javascript is much faster.

My problem is I can't for the life of me figure out how to insert the new rows after or before the given table row.  I have tried the insertBefore, insertAfter, and appendTo methods but the problem is that the newRows variable is just an html string not an actual DOM node.  Is there a way to just insert the html before or after the reference table row without having to convert the html string of table rows into DOM elements?

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle example of your problem

Comment: The DOM isn't a string. Why not just create your rows properly?

Comment: "Properly" is relative.  They are being created properly but they have to be filled with data from a database.  This is an ASP.NET MVC application and I am utilizing it to return a partial view that contains all the "properly" formed table rows that would take way to much javascript and client side logic to create.

Answer (score 0):

You can try return an array of objects(json) and use this array to create new rows via JS and append them to where you want.

Comment: This is a possibility but there is quite a bit of logic required in generating the HTML rows and duplicating that logic in javascript would be horrendous.

Answer (score 0):

You can use innerHTML, but would take a little thinking in your case, since you want to just append the rows, rather than completely overwrite the content. using innerHTML is always faster than DOM manipulation. Perhaps you could put the rows in a new table, but put the table beneath the existing one to make it look like its part of it? Personally, I'm curious about the jquery speed, I've found jquery is usually not the source of the problem, and more how it is being used-

Comment: The document fragment suggestion is also good, it's the natural way to proceed if you're using the innerHTML approach I suggested-

Answer (score 0):

What you can do to convert your string is create an empty div and set the string as it's innerHTML. They will get converted to DOM and will be accessible via the div childNodes;

Then you can use a document fragment to insert all the DOM elements in it, using appendChild()

When that's done you just insert your document fragment, so only one insertion instead of multiple one on the actual document.

A good piece on document fragment http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/